# Lint check crashes with java.lang.NullPointerException (ECJ compiler crashed)

Tags: android, lint

When running the `lintVitalRelease` check on my app sources, the following crash occurs:

```
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease
ECJ compiler crashed processing D:\PROJECTS\xxxxx\app\src\main\java\com\xxxxx\xxxxx\utils\images\ImageUtil.java
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.internalAnalyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:739)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.analyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.analyseCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:118)
        at com.android.tools.lint.EcjParser$NonGeneratingCompiler.process(EcjParser.java:1416)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processCompiledUnits(Compiler.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:417)
        at com.android.tools.lint.EcjParser.parse(EcjParser.java:549)
```

I was able to break down this issue to the following lines of code:

```
public static void startFromGalleryIntent(Fragment f) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        f.startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT_RESOLVER);
    }
```

As soon as I comment out the last line:

`// f.startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT_RESOLVER);`

the `lintVitalRelease` finishes without problems.

I'm using the latest stable build tools (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`)

Who can explain what is going on, and how to solve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Lint has some issues with lambdas.
Same issue happened to me for project with Java source code with sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

I've found that a static method from the class in question (in your case ImageUtil.java) was invoked somewhere else from lambda. Replacing there lambda with anonymous class resolved it